# Raw thumbnail working in Thunar but not in Nautilus

Tags: arch-linux, nautilus, thunar, thumbnails

I am using Arch with Gnome 3. I installed `raw-thumbnailer` using `pacman` and got raw thumbnails working in `Thunar`. I thought installing `raw-thumbnailer` will also make `Nautilus` to show raw thumbnails. But nautilus is not showing raw thumbnails. How can I make nautilus show raw thumbnails?

I have `raw-thumbnailer 0.2.1-2` installed. Any help would be much appreciated.